# Create a custom role in Openstack to provide read-only access for a single tenant?

Tags: openstack, keystone

I'm running devstack (master from github as of 11/21/2014) with the Horizon v2 api (default) and I want to create a read-only user account/role for viewing a single tenant's resources.  I'm fairly new to things, and /etc/nova/policy.json and /etc/keystone/policy.json make very little sense right now.

Has anyone created a role that permits just viewing things and no edits/updates/changes?  If so, any advice on how to accomplish that?

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing. I don't suppose you ever found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Rocky Release of Openstack have introduced Reader role.

refer:- https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest/admin/service-api-protection.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.